# lodash _.includes not evaluating to true or false in angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have set `$rootScope._ = window._; in app.run and $scope._ = _;` in controller.
However when I am trying to evaluate via _.includes, the variables inside are evaluated fine (I can see that by inspecting element) but ng-disabled is not evaluating to any boolean value.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="acLink in accordion.links">
    href="#/{{acLink.domain}}/{{acLink.id}}" uib-tooltip="{{acLink.title}}" ng-disabled="_.includes({{allowedRoles}},{{acLink.role_d}})" style="color:#4d4d4d">{{acLink.title}}</a>
</li>

<a href="#/abc/home" uib-tooltip="CBOE Home" ng-disabled="_.includes(["abc", "xyz"],'abc')" style="color:#4d4d4d" class="ng-binding" aria-disabled="false"> Home</a>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
angular.min.js:103 Error: [$parse:syntax]
 at http://localhost:63342/dashboard_core/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at hb.throwError (http://localhost:63342/dashboard_core/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:190:254)
    at hb.primary (http://localhost:63342/dashboard_core/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:189:477)
    at hb.unary (http://localhost:63342/dashboard_core/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:197:82)
    at hb.multiplicative (http://localhost:63342/dashboard_core/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:196:324)
    at hb.additive (http://localhost:63342/dashboard_core/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:196:182)
    at hb.relational (http://localhost:63342/dashboard_core/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:196:48)
    at hb.equality (http://localhost:63342/dashboard_core/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:195:418)
    at hb.logicalAND (http://localhost:63342/dashboard_core/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:195:294) <a href="#/{{acLink.domain}}/{{acLink.id}}" uib-tooltip="{{acLink.title}}" ng-disabled="_.includes({{allowedRoles}},{{acLink.role_d}})" style="color:#4d4d4d" class="ng-binding">
```

Comment: Better create a function rather than inline JS.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the code snippet. I see now that you're generating those values you want to include using interpolation. In that case, Tushar's suggestion of moving the function to your controller code rather than passing lodash to the view is a better option.

```
// HTML
ng-disabled="includes(allowedRoles, acLink.role_d)"

// JS
$scope.includes = function(list, item) {
    _.includes(list, item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a separate function for this. 
example:

```
$scope.isDisabled = function(){
    return _.includes(["abc", "xyz"],'abc');
};

<a href="#/abc/home" uib-tooltip="CBOE Home" ng-disabled="isDisabled()" style="color:#4d4d4d" class="ng-binding" aria-disabled="false"> Home</a>
```